# ESI and EDI Overflow

Tags: windows, buffer-overflow

I tried fuzzing an application and ended up with my fuzz string in the EDI register and my program stopped with access violation when reading ESI. I checked the SEH, but it seems un affected :( I am new to this field and have only seen buffer overflows affecting EIP till now! can someone guide me on how to proceed?
[image]